# How to find and show multiple items from a List using a single item?

Tags: c#

```
    //declaring new list
    List<Student>studentslist=new List<Student>();
    public Student student;        
    //Save Button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.regNo = regNoTextBox.Text;
        student.firstName = firstNameTextBox.Text;
        student.lastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;
        student.GetFullName();

        if (studentslist.Any(item => item.regNo == student.regNo) == false)
        {
            studentslist.Add(student);
            regNoTextBox.Text = "";
            firstNameTextBox.Text = "";
            LastNameTextBox.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Information Saved.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Reg.No is alresy exist !");
        }
```

Here, I am adding unique Reg.No for the Students. Now I want to enter any saved Reg.No and then press Find Button then it will show corresponding student Name in MessageBox. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can search for a student using unique registration value like

```
Student s=studentlists.Where(item=>item.regNo==textbox_regNumber).FirstorDefault();
if(s!=null)
{
   MessageBox.Show(s.studentName + " Class: " +s.class +" Section: "+s.section);
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Not Found")
}
```

Comment: dear @ali softhub,  MessageBox.Show(s.studentName); shows error !

Comment: check s.firstName

Comment: this property was just for sample. you can show any Student class public property here

Comment: thanks it works. But if I save Roll No, Name, Class, Section for a particular student, then how can I get all the information using Reg.No/Roll No?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `dictionary` if you want unique students by `regNo`:

```
    var studentsList =Dictionary<string, Student>` for adding students with unique regNo:

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var regNo = regNoTextBox.Text;
        if(!studentsList.ContainsKey(regNo))
        {
            Student student = new Student();
            student.regNo = regNoTextBox.Text;
            student.firstName = firstNameTextBox.Text;
            student.lastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;
            student.GetFullName();
            studentsList.Add(regNo, student);
            regNoTextBox.Text = "";
            firstNameTextBox.Text = "";
            LastNameTextBox.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Information Saved.");
        }        
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Reg.No already exists !");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ αNerd yes, by using dictionary it will be easy, but if I saved multiple information for a particular student like Name, Section, Department etc. then how can I get all this information by just using the Reg.No/Roll No?

Comment: Sorry, I meant Dictionary<string, Student>. It adds (regNo, student) so it should have student as value. To get firstName of student  with given regNo for example you can write var firstName = studentsList[regNo].firstName.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Student>studentslist=new List<Student>();
public Student student;        
//Save Button
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Student student = new Student();
    student.regNo = regNoTextBox.Text;
    student.firstName = firstNameTextBox.Text;
    student.lastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;
    student.GetFullName();
    Student s=studentlists.Where(item=>item.regNo==textbox_regNumber).FirstorDefault();

    if(s!==null)
    {
        studentslist.Add(student);
        regNoTextBox.Text = "";
        firstNameTextBox.Text = "";
        LastNameTextBox.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Information Saved.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Reg.No is alresy exist !");
    }
}
```